# Why does "head -3" give the same results as "head -n 3"?

Tags: linux, coreutils

I'm interested in why `head` works as it works with given parameters, i.e. `head -3` produces the same output as `head -n 3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Coreutils info pages for `head` (accessible through `info coreutils 'head invocation'`):

> For compatibility `head` also supports an obsolete option syntax
>   `-COUNTOPTIONS`, which is recognized only if it is specified first.
>   `COUNT` is a decimal number optionally followed by a size letter (`b`,
>   `k`, `m`) as in `-c`, or `l` to mean count by lines, or other option
>   letters (`cqv`). Scripts intended for standard hosts should use `-c
>   COUNT` or `-n COUNT` instead.

This is why the syntax is equivalent. `man head` doesn't tell you this, by the way.